# How do I strip the "$" symbol from a string in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

In need of dire help. I am trying to conditionally iterate over the rows of a Google play store csv file. I keep running to the issue of pandas not recognizing the '>=' symbol during some of my loops for some reason. That said using the condition "if price == "9.00" works just fine but the other operations (i.e, '<=' and ">=" return error messages.

Additionally, I'm trying to count the number of apps with a price of $9.00 or greater. I want to strip the "$" symbol from the price column and then proceed to iterate over it. I have attempted the str.lstrip function with no success. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

````
df = pd.read_csv("googleplaystore.csv")

df['Rating'].fillna(value = '0.0', inplace = True)

# Calculating how many apps have a price of $9.00 or greater

apps_morethan9 = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rating = float(row.Rating)
    price = float(row.Price)
    if price >= 9:
        apps_morethan9 += 1

print(apps_morethan9)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-66171ce7efb6> in <module>
      5 for i, row in df.iterrows():
      6     rating = float(row.Rating)
----> 7     price = float(row.Price)
      8     if price >= 9:
      9         apps_morethan9 += 1

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$4.99'```
````

Comment: `row.Price.str.strip("$")`? or `str.lstrip("$")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use string.replace() like:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rating = float(row.Rating)
    price = float(row.Price.str.replace('$',''))
    if price >= 9:
        apps_morethan9 += 1
```

but your implementation could be improved in terms of speed and complexity:

```
print(df[df.Price.str.replace('$','').astype(float) >= 9].count().values[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies. Truly appreciated that this forum is so cool. I tried the code you suggested using string.replace but got this error message

``` 

apps_morethan = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rating = row.Rating
    price = float(row.Price.replace('$','')
    if price >= '9':
        apps_morethan += 1File "<ipython-input-169-635132b4653b>", line 7
    if price >= '9':
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```

Comment: Thank you kindly. You guys are the best.

Comment: mark the answer as solution with the green hook if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can apply str.replace on the whole Series before iterating over it like so:

```
df["Price"].str.replace("$", "")
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #rest of your routine
```

I suggest you to use @gustavz solution for improved performance

Comment: I appreciate it the assistance. Thank you guys so much.